# Что делает следующее выражение: (n & (n - 1)) != 0

Tags: objective-c

В описании вакансии "Разработчик мобильных приложений для iOS" от компании Яндекс есть вопрос:

**Объясните, что делает следующее выражение: 
(n & (n - 1)) != 0**

Comment: Вопрос совершенно бессмысленный и не имеющий ответа, пока не оговорен конкретный тип объекта `n`.

Comment: @Ivan Kramarchuk  "Неплохо знать C или C++" - это означает иметь на сайте www.stackoverflow.com золотые знаки отличия по меткам C или C++. Все остальное - это всего лишь ваше личное самовнушение..:)

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow Это скорее "Отлично знать" :)

Comment: @IvanKramarchuk Нет, это всего лишь подтверждение того, что знаешь основы языка.

Comment: @AnT верно, но вид формулы намекает на проверку степени двойки для натурального числа: [How to check if a number is a power of 2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/600293/4279). `&` указывает, что целые числа рассматриваются, для signed результат побитовой операции в общем случае от реализации может зависеть, но по смыслу выражения только положительные числа интересно тестировать здесь (если намерение вопроса не поговорить о возможных представлениях чисел, trap representation, etc).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Вернемся к истокам...

**Что означает A & B == 0?...** Это означает, что А и B не содержат на одних и тех же позициях единичных битов.

## Что произойдет?

Когда вы отнимаете единицу, посмотрите на младший бит. 1 вы замените на 0. Но если там стоит 0, то вы должны заимствовать из старшего бита. Вы изменяете каждый бит с 0 на 1, пока не дойдете до 1. Затем вы инвертируете единицу в ноль, — все готово. Таким образом, можно сказать, что n - 1 будет совпадать с n в каких-то битах, за исключением того, что младшим нулям в n соответствуют единицы в n - 1, а последний единичный бит в n становится нулем в n - 1.

## Что значит n & (n - 1) !== 0?

`n` и `n - 1` не содержат общих единиц. Предположим, они имеют вид:

```
n = abcde1000

n - 1 = abcde0111
```

abcde должны быть нулевыми битами, то есть n имеет вид `000001000`. Таким образом, значение n — степень двойки.

**Итак, наш ответ**: логическое выражение `((n & (n-1)) !== 0)` истинно, если n не является степенью двойки и не равно нулю.

Comment: Ноль уже не является степенью двойки, поэтому "и не равно нулю" излишне. Стоит упомянуть какие типы рассматриваются и поведение для чисел со знаком.

Answer (score 3):

Данное выражение

```
(n & (n - 1)) != 0
```

проверяет, что число `n` содержит более, чем один бит, установленный в единицу.

Comment: В какой практической задаче это может использоваться?

Comment: @IvanKramarchuk Например, в подсчете числа установленных битов в числе, или является ли число степенью 2.

Answer (score 1):

так проверяется является ли число `n` степенью двойки так как именно у таких чисел только один единичный бит в двоичном представлении